# Maven Clojure Plugin Not Running Tests

Tags: java, maven, junit, clojure, maven-3

I am trying to create a simple project with maven that uses Java, Scala, and Clojure. I have simple test classes for each language, however when running `mvn test`, the clojure tests are not executing.

I am using the [clojure-maven-plugin](https://github.com/talios/clojure-maven-plugin) to compile and test the clojure code, and when running the mvn goal `mvn clojure:test-with-junit` it runs as expected and I get the following output:

```
[INFO] --- clojure-maven-plugin:1.3.20:test-with-junit (default-cli) @ functional-programming-patterns ---
Tests run: 2, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0
There are test failures.
```

Though, when I just run `mvn test`, I only get my Java and Scala tests to run:

```
Running main.HelloWorldJavaTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.06 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running main.HelloWorldScalaTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.312 sec <<< FAILURE!

Results :

Failed tests:   fail(main.HelloWorldJavaTest): expected:<1> but was:<2>

Tests in error:
  fail(main.HelloWorldScalaTest): 1 did not equal 2

Tests run: 4, Failures: 1, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
```

My [plugin](https://github.com/DWiechert/functional-programming-patterns/blob/master/pom.xml#L120) is configured as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.theoryinpractise</groupId>
    <artifactId>clojure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.20</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>clojure-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sourceDirectories>
                    <sourceDirectory>src/main/clojure</sourceDirectory>
                </sourceDirectories>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>clojure-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-with-junit</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <testSourceDirectories>
                    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/clojure</testSourceDirectory>
                </testSourceDirectories>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <sourceDirectories>
            <sourceDirectory>src/main/clojure</sourceDirectory>
        </sourceDirectories>
        <testSourceDirectories>
            <testSourceDirectory>src/test/clojure</testSourceDirectory>
        </testSourceDirectories>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I was just wondering if there was something I'm missing in the plug-in that causes my Clojure tests to not run when both my Scala and Java ones run.

**UPDATE**

I have been playing around with this some more and it appears that it is not properly binding to the `mvn test` phase. When I switch the phase the plugin is tied to from `test` to `process-test-resources`, the test run just fine. However, since I have failed tests, the Java and Scala ones do not run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more trial and error, I found out that the Clojure plugin would not run if there were test failures in either the Java or Scala tests. However, if all of the Java and Scala tests passed, it would run the Clojure tests as expected.

I have logged [an issue](https://github.com/talios/clojure-maven-plugin/issues/94) with the plugin.